# Filter data based on query and return result using Partial view

Tags: c#, .net, ajax, forms, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to filter data based on a query. I am using a partial view to show the filtered data. However, nothing is updated in the partial view. How can I fix this?

Controller class:

```
public IActionResult Index() {
    IEnumerable<Organisation> organisations = _organisationRepository.GetAll().OrderBy(b => b.Name).ToList();

    if (isAjaxRequest()) {
        string text = Request.Form["text"].ToString();
        return PartialView("_Organisations", _organisationRepository.GetByName(text).ToList());
        }

        return View(organisations);
    }

private bool isAjaxRequest() {
        return Request != null && Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest";
    }
```

Organisation View:

```
<form asp-controller="Organisation" asp-action="Index">
<div class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">

        <label for="text">Filteren in organisaties</label>
        <input type="text" name="text" id="text" required pattern="^([0-9]{4}|[a-zA-Z]+)$">

        <label for="selected"></label>
        <select name="selected" id="selected" class="form-control">
            <option value="name">Naam</option>
            <option value="postalcode">Postcode</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="search">Zoeken</button>
</div>
</form>

<div id="partial">
    @Html.Partial("_Organisations", Model);
</div>
```

Partial view:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-bordered">
<tr>
    <th>Naam</th>
    <th>Adres</th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @item.Name
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.Location.ToString()
        </td>
        <td>
            <a onClick="showForm(this, @item.OrganisationId)" href="#">Selecteer</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Javascript file:

```
$("#search").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
    url: "Organisation/Index",
    type: "post",
    data: $("form").serialize(),
    success: function (result) {
        $("#partial").html(result);
        }
    });
});
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First answer (not correct):** If it's not a typo, you forgot a $ in jquery `$("#search").click(function () {`.

**New answer:** I think here is the bug: you must prevent the normal behavior of the click event. Change your javascript function (2 modifications):

```
        $("#search").click(function (e) {

            e.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                url: "Organisation/Index",
                type: "post",
                data: $("form").serialize(),
                success: function (result) {
                    $("#partial").html(result);
                }
            });
        });
```

Now the function is taking e (the event) in parameter and before we make the Ajax call, we need to call `e.preventDefault();` The bug was that the Ajax call returned the partial view, the #partial html was updated, but then the normal behavior of the "click" would reload the page with a HTTP GET request

Comment: It was a typo! Thanks to let me know I changed it in the question!

Comment: All right. There must be another little bug in the code we can not see. Have you tried to inspect every calls?
1. Put a breakpoint in your javascript at $.ajax call
2. Put a breakpoint at the entrance of Index action controller (running in Visual Studio in Debugging)
3. insert the partialview result in a variable before to return it and put a breakpoint there to make sure that you are getting something from the view
4. put a 2nd breakpoint in Javascript, in the success function
It is a good start. Tell us which breakpoints are reached or not

Comment: Okay, so the first two breakpoints are reached. I discovered something strange when I continued debugging. When I do not enter any text inside the html input box, the variable text is empty in the controller, and it returns a partial view containing all the elements that contain "empty" string, wich are in my case all the elements. Strangely when I do enter text inside the html input box the controller returns the View(organisations) and after that it returns the partial view, but nothing visual is changed on the page.

Comment: I got it. I edited my answer and it should work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the help! It worked! I marked your anwser as the solution!